# Golang time error: month out of range

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
time.Parse(time.Now().String()[0:19],time.Now().String()[0:19])
```

error:

```
parsing time "2016-09-20 16:50:08": month out of range
```

How to parse time string?

Answer (score 1):

First param is layout, see:

```
func Parse(layout, value string) (Time, error) {
    return parse(layout, value, UTC, Local)
}
```

Docs:

> ```
> // Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents.
> // The layout  defines the format by showing how the reference time,
> // defined to be
> //    Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> // would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of
> // the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the
> // input string.
> //
> // Predefined layouts ANSIC, UnixDate, RFC3339 and others describe standard
> // and convenient representations of the reference time. For more information
> // about the formats and the definition of the reference time, see the
> // documentation for ANSIC and the other constants defined by this package.
> // Also, the executable example for time.Format demonstrates the working
> // of the layout string in detail and is a good reference.
> //
> // Elements omitted from the value are assumed to be zero or, when
> // zero is impossible, one, so parsing "3:04pm" returns the time
> // corresponding to Jan 1, year 0, 15:04:00 UTC (note that because the year is
> // 0, this time is before the zero Time).
> // Years must be in the range 0000..9999. The day of the week is checked
> // for syntax but it is otherwise ignored.
> //
> // In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.
> //
> // When parsing a time with a zone offset like -0700, if the offset corresponds
> // to a time zone used by the current location (Local), then Parse uses that
> // location and zone in the returned time. Otherwise it records the time as
> // being in a fabricated location with time fixed at the given zone offset.
> //
> // No checking is done that the day of the month is within the month's
> // valid dates; any one- or two-digit value is accepted. For example
> // February 31 and even February 99 are valid dates, specifying dates
> // in March and May. This behavior is consistent with time.Date.
> //
> // When parsing a time with a zone abbreviation like MST, if the zone abbreviation
> // has a defined offset in the current location, then that offset is used.
> // The zone abbreviation "UTC" is recognized as UTC regardless of location.
> // If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being
> // in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset.
> // This choice means that such a time can be parsed and reformatted with the
> // same layout losslessly, but the exact instant used in the representation will
> // differ by the actual zone offset. To avoid such problems, prefer time layouts
> // that use a numeric zone offset, or use ParseInLocation.
> ```

---

You may use

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", time.Now().String()[:19])
```

Try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zDGYkRucKF):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", time.Now().String()[:19])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I came here to say golang will some times mean "month" they meant "DAY OF THE MONTH", the error message is wrong, here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

dateAsString:= "31/Oct/2019"

layout := "01/Jan/2006" // BAD BAD BAD SHOULD BE 02 INSTEAD OF 01
fmt.Println("INPUT:" + dateAsString)

t, err := time.Parse(layout, dateAsString)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("DATE UNPARSEABLE:3", err)

}
fmt.Println(t)

}
```